# Programming an upload speed test using java sockets

Tags: java, sockets, http, networking, post

I'm currently working on an upload test using java sockets. I've found an example using httpurlconnection but for the purposes of my assignment I must do it manually with sockets. Also, the server I will be using, does not accept HTTP PUT requests, and only accepts POST requests. Therefore, in there I have a line which looks like this:

```
    conn = new Socket(server, 80);
    outToServer = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    outToServer.writeBytes("POST...etc...");
```

I am not quite sure how to format the POST request. Here is how I had formated the PUT request which failed because the server I am using does not accept PUT requests:

```
    outToServer.writeBytes("PUT /url/test1.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                           + "Host: url.edu\r\n"
                           + "Content-Type: plain/text\r\n"
                           + "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Socket conn = new Socket(server, 80);

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
writer.write("POST " + "http://www.example.com" + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
writer.write("Content-Length: " + data.length() + "\r\n");
wr.write("Content-Type: plain/text\r\n");
writer.write("\r\n");

writer.write(data);
writer.flush();
```

Comment: I tried that and this is the response from the server I got: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 15 May 2014 02:13:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (FreeBSD) PHP/5.4.10 mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8n DAV/2
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>